# IntelliJ IDEA: Abnormal build process termination - how to fix?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build, process, termination

I am trying to build the project and get the following response. 
Do you know that can be a reason for this?

```
Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.2/bin/java -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=-2950067676013085039 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2019.1 -Didea.home.path=/snap/intellij-idea-community/137 -Didea.config.path=/home/UserName/.IdeaIC2019.1/config -Didea.plugins.path=/home/UserName/.IdeaIC2019.1/config/plugins -Djps.log.dir=/home/UserName/.IdeaIC2019.1/system/log/build-log -Djps.fallback.jdk.home=/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/jre64 -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=1.8.0_202-release -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/UserName/.IdeaIC2019.1/system/compile-server/PROJECTtesting_95b68bfb/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"/tmp/kotlin-idea-1561620976944961936-is-running\" -classpath /snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.2/lib/classes.zip org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher /snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/netty-common-4.1.32.Final.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/jps-builders.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/lz4-1.3.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/aether-transport-file-1.1.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/asm-all-7.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/aether-spi-1.1.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/forms_rt.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/util.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/aether-util-1.1.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/aether-transport-http-1.1.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/annotations.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/httpcore-4.4.10.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/jdom.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/guava-25.1-jre.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/maven-builder-support-3.3.9.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/netty-buffer-4.1.32.Final.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/jna.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/forms-1.1-preview.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/maven-model-3.3.9.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/jna-platform.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/platform-api.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.3.9.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.6.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/httpclient-4.5.6.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/javac2.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/maven-artifact-3.3.9.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/resources_en.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/jps-builders-6.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/aether-api-1.1.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/netty-codec-4.1.32.Final.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/aether-connector-basic-1.1.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/jps-model.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/netty-transport-4.1.32.Final.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/trove4j.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/aether-impl-1.1.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/idea_rt.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/maven-model-builder-3.3.9.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/netty-resolver-4.1.32.Final.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.3.9.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/log4j.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/gson-2.8.5.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/guava-25.1-jre.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/android/lib/common-26.3.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-4.10.3.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/gson-2.8.5.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/lib/guava-25.1-jre.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/android/lib/common-26.3.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-4.10.3.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/ui-designer-jps-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/intellilang-jps-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-rt-constants.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/eclipse/lib/common-eclipse-util.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-jps-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/android/lib/android-common.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/android/lib/build-common.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/android/lib/android-rt.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/android/lib/android-extensions-ide.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/android/lib/sdk-common-26.3.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/android/lib/common-26.3.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/android/lib/repository-26.3.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/android/lib/sdklib-26.3.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/android/lib/layoutlib-api-26.3.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/android/lib/manifest-merger-26.3.0.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/137/plugins/javaFX/lib/common-javaFX-plugin.jar org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 38501 8bbba966-6697-4872-9844-9ec0c4013681 /home/UserName/.IdeaIC2019.1/system/compile-server
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x00007fbb06277012, pid=15695, tid=15696#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (11.0.2+9) (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0xbaa012]  Modules::define_module(_jobject*, unsigned char, _jstring*, _jstring*, char const* const*, int, Thread*)+0x22#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P" (or dumping to /home/UserName/.IdeaIC2019.1/system/compile-server/core.15695)#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/UserName/.IdeaIC2019.1/system/compile-server/hs_err_pid15695.log#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I have an answer.
The solution was to remove all javas (especially OpenJDK) and Install Oracle version. 
now it is fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Something has been set up incorrectly. For me, one of my project was not added as maven project. Right click on pom, and i got the option to do so. But it could be anything minor setup issue.